# assigned value to variable return undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm following a french tutorial and i'm stuck with a undefined variable, maybe i missed something, seems the value is assigned to the variable but i can't get access to it maybe a scope issue ?.

```
function Tileset(url) {
    // Chargement de l'image dans l'attribut image
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.referenceDuTileset = this;
    this.image.onload = function() {
        if(!this.complete) 
            throw new Error("Erreur de chargement du tileset nommÃ© \"" + url + "\".");

        // Largeur du tileset en tiles
        this.referenceDuTileset.largeur = this.width / 32;
    }

    this.image.src = "tilesets/" + url;
}

Tileset.prototype.dessinerTile = function(numero, context, xDestination, yDestination) {
    var xSourceEnTiles = numero % this.largeur;
    console.log(this);
    if(xSourceEnTiles == 0) xSourceEnTiles = this.largeur;
    var ySourceEnTiles = Math.ceil(numero / this.largeur);
    var xSource = (xSourceEnTiles - 1) * 32;
    var ySource = (ySourceEnTiles - 1) * 32;
    context.drawImage(this.image, xSource, ySource, 32, 32, xDestination, yDestination, 32, 32);
}
```

Output of console.log(this):

```
-> Tileset {image: img, dessinerTile: function}
-> image: img 
largeur: 6
-> __proto__: Tileset
```

Output of console.log(this.largeur)

```
undefined
```

Comment: this.largeur is not defined in the prototype.dessinerTile. Thats wats causing it to crash! Try this.referenceDuTileset.largeur instead.

Comment: @PhilipG u mean this.image.referenceDuTileset ? because this.referenceDuTileset.largeur return
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'largeur' of undefined